# Why undefined variable when using function() use($var){}?

Tags: php

```
$isac_start = microtime(true);

function ilog($m) use ($isac_start){

  $time_elapsed_secs = microtime(true) - $isac_start;
  file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/debug_log.txt', $m . " - time elapsed: " . $time_elapsed_secs . "\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```

gives me

undefined variable `$isac_start`;

why? how to fix it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that PHP's `use` syntax is only valid on anonymous functions. I have no idea why that's the case; I find it disconcerting that named and anonymous functions are treated so differently…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `use` keyword is intended to be used with [closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (see example 3), it is not intended to be used with regular functions. The following demonstrates correct usage:

```
$isac_start = microtime(true);

$ilog = function ($m) use ($isac_start) {
    var_dump($m);
    var_dump($isac_start);
};
$ilog('hello');
```

Answer (score 2):

`use` isn't applicable to named functions, only to anonymous functions. In order to get `$isac_start` into the function scope, you should probably just pass it as an additional argument, as in:

```
function ilog($m, $isac_start) { ...
```

`use` exists in order for anonymous functions to be able to inherit variables from the parent scope, which isn't really necessary for normal user-defined functions.